# Application like Dots join and dash in android

Tags: android, dashboard

I am supposed to develop an application in android and the concept is very similar to dots game.
[image]

As I am new to this concept, I don't have any idea about the development base. Also I don't know whether it is possible to develop such application in android or not.

Do I need to use canvas or any other tools? 
Can any one please suggest me how I should get started with this or any guidelines for this application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didnt download it but check this : http://code.google.com/p/kaesekaestchen/

Answer (score 1):

3 (simple) steps:

1. learn java
2. get android concepts
3. learn about android games devlopment libs like Android sdk or
   [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/blog/) or [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) or unity

check that for more [Android games development SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360909/android-games-development-sdk)